# Laravel Blade - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

this is a part of my array (sturmCluster).

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Tom
                    [Punkte] => 8
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Dave
                    [Punkte] => 8
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Christian
                    [Punkte] => 12
                )

        )
)
```

And my function returns with

```
return view('cluster')->with('sturmCluster');
```

In the view I try to get data from the array with

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    <label for="">Test</label>
    @foreach($sturmCluster)
        {{"$sturmCLuster->Name"}}<br/>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

How can I handle the array with blade. For my first test, I want only to return all Name Values from array.

Comment: I think you need to go deep one more level in the array, like this `@foreach($sturmCluster[0] as $cluster)` or pass it to the view like: `return view('cluster')->with('sturmCluster', $sturmCluster[0]);`

Comment: At least `@foreach($sturmCluster as $item)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foreach($strumCluster as $key=>$sturmCluster)
    {{$sturmCLuster['Name']}}<br/>
@endforeach
```

try this.

Comment: This works but because of return view('cluster')->with('sturmCluster', $newerarray[1]); I get only the [1] array part. But I need all.

Comment: Okay I have the solution it is $sturmCluster[0]['Name']

Answer (score 0):

So your array looks like this

```
$sturmCluster = array(
        array(
            array('Name'=>'Tom','Punkte'=>8),
            array('Name'=>'Dave','Punkte'=>8),
            array('Name'=>'Christian','Punkte'=>12)
        )
);
```

You can pass the entire array to the view without having to explicitly pass the first element of sturmCluster array.

```
return view('cluster')->with('sturmCluster',$sturmCluster);
```

And run the loop as:

```
@foreach($sturmCluster as $array)
   @foreach($array as $subarray)
       {{$subarray['Name']}}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```